# Coordinates of a regular unit n-simplex

Tags: geometry, simplex

The Cartesian coordinates of a regular $n$-simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with all edge lengths 1 and centered on the origin is given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Cartesian_coordinates_for_a_regular_n-dimensional_simplex_in_Rn) by

> $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\mathbf{e}_i - \frac{1}{n\sqrt{2}}(1 \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{n + 1}}) \cdot (1, \dots, 1),$ for $1 \le i \le n$,
>
> and additional point
>
> $\mp\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n + 1}} \cdot (1, \dots, 1)$

where $\mathbf{e}_i$ are the base vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. These expressions seem to be wrong.

For example for the simplest case of the 1-simplex we have $n=1$ in $\mathbb{R}^1$, $\mathbf{e}_1=1$ and get the coordinates

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot1 - \frac{1}{1\cdot\sqrt{2}}(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 1}})=-\frac{1}{2}$

and

$-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1 + 1}}=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$

As we have $\pm$ and $\mp$ in the original formulas I used for the first formula the $+$ and in the second formula the $-$ sign. The coordinates for the 1-simplex are neither centered nor have edge length 1. The correct coordinates are $\pm \frac{1}{2}$. Furthermore the notation $(1,\ldots,1)$ seems to be superficial in the first formula.

What is the right formula? Or is the formula right and just misinterpreted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was asked almost 3 years ago and the definition was indeed wrong. Meanwhile it was corrected in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Cartesian_coordinates_for_a_regular_n-dimensional_simplex_in_Rn), now we read (changes red)

> $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\mathbf{e}_i - \frac{1}{n\sqrt{2}}(1 \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{n + 1}}) \cdot \color{green}{(1, \dots, 1)},$ for $1 \le i \le n$,
>
> and additional point
>
> $\color{red}\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{\color{red}2(n + 1)}} \cdot (1, \dots, 1)$

The vector of ones in the first line (green) is indeed not needed in the notation but does not influence the result.

For $n=1$ we get the vertex pair $(-\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2})$ if we use positive sign and the vertex pair $(+\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2})$ for negative sign. The pairs are centered and have a distance of $1$.